# Need advice on documenting LAMP web site

Tags: mysql, php, lamp, documentation

I need to document my web site. It is a music web site on Linux/Apache/MySQL/PHP on AWS. I need to document everything: architecture (5 servers), database (100+ tables), php classes, programming constructs, and process flows. I'm familiar with phpdoc.  Otherwise, I'm not sure what are the best tools.  I would like tools compatible with industry standard UML.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there are two important criteria that the tool must satisfy:

- At least one person on the team must have experience using the tool.
- The data must be stored in text files.

The second criteria is such that you can store the files in a version control system. Tracking revisions on binary files is a no-go.

If multiple tools satisfy both criteria for you, then let the people who have experience with the tools come to an agreement on which one to use.